# how to display different user controls based on the selection of ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a list of filters. Users can decide to use how many filters by clicking "add" or "remove" to add/remove 1.(I already implement this).

Each filter is originally a comboBox that contains filter options, say Name and Sex. When choosing Name, it displays a textbox near the combobox, when choosing Sex, it display 2 radio buttons male/female.

```
<ComboBox Name="FilterComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding FilterOptions}"...>
<Button Command="{Binding RemoveFilterCommand}....">
```

That means Name correponds to a textbox, Sex corresponds to a radiobutton group and so on.

Instead of setting visibility of textbox, radio button group, etc. on the back end code. Is there a way to implement it using something like data template/item selector in .xaml? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `DataTrigger`s.

I've created a simple class `Filter`, that holds the collection of possible filter types (name, sex) and has a property `SelectedType` that indicates what type has been selected.

#### Filter.cs

```cs
public class Filter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<string> Types { get; set; }

    private string _selectedType;
    public string SelectedType
    {
        get => _selectedType;
        set
        {
            _selectedType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Filter()
    {
        Types = new List<string>
        {
            "Name",
            "Sex"
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Everything else is happening in the MainWindow.xaml

- I'm using an array in the `Grid`'s `Resources` to hold the collection of filters, that would be somewhere in your view model, but this is just an example.
- I'm using an `ItemsControl` to hold the filters and a template for a single filter is defined in `ItemsControl`'s `ItemTemplate` property.

#### MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="TempWpfApp02.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TempWpfApp02"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <x:Array x:Key="filters" Type="{x:Type local:Filter}">
                <local:Filter />
            </x:Array>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource filters}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType}" />

                        <TextBox>
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedType}" Value="Name">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>

                        <RadioButton Content="Female" GroupName="SexGroup">
                            <RadioButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedType}" Value="Sex">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </RadioButton.Style>
                        </RadioButton>

                        <RadioButton Content="Male" GroupName="SexGroup">
                            <RadioButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedType}" Value="Sex">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </RadioButton.Style>
                        </RadioButton>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```